# How is 65535 bytes is total length of IP datagram?

Tags: ip, ipv4

> The maximum size of an IPv4 packet is 65,535 because the Total Length field is a 16-bit unsigned integer, which has a possible 65,536 values (from 0 to 65,535).

This created 2 confusions for me.

1. Say we have 1 bit number. Then there are 2 possible values. 0 and 1. Say, each value occupies 1 byte in memory. Then it is of size 2 bytes. i.e 2^1 byte is the size of memory not 2^1-1 byte.
2. I am confused with the concept of addressing and how it works here. All I can understand from a  16 bit number is that it would mean values from 0 to 65,535. So how does that corresponds to 65535 bytes? This is a very basic question I know but I am getting very confused as I am new to networking.

Answer (score 3):

It is because the number in that field is the number of octets (bytes) for the entire packet. You could never have a number less than 20 because that is the minimum IPv4 header size. If he field has 65,535 in it, then that is the packet size.

Whatever number that field has is the size of the packet. A 16-bit number tops out at 65,535. Yes, there are 65,536 different values, but some of the smaller values cannot be used. The number is the number of octets (bytes) in the packet.

Comment: You could theoretically define the size in such a way that you shift the number by 1, since a size of 0 does not make sense. You could even shift it by 20, since a smaller size is impossible. But it would be pretty confusing for very little gain.